# sql pivot table The column 'CreateDate' was specified multiple times for PIV

Tags: sql, pivot-table

MY QUERY;

```
SELECT *
FROM MR_METOLAMA M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MR_METOLAMA_DETAIL MD  ON M.UserTableID=MD.MasterTableID
PIVOT 
(SUM(ma_quantity_detail) FOR ma_bodysize_detail IN ([s],[m],[x],[l])) PIV
```

But bug is 'The column 'CreateDate' was specified multiple times for 'PIV'.'

Comment: I assume both tables MR_METOLAMA and MR_METOLAMA_DETAIL have CreateDate.  Instead of doing select * retrieve only the required columns.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried this one but result not change.

Comment: you'll need to tell it which table you want createDate from. Say you have columns A B C in M and A D E in MD then and you only want A from M and D from MD then you need to specify that.  Select M.A, MD.D FROM....

Otherwise it doesn't know which table you want A from and it won't just guess.